# How can i modify Unique ID in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have one unique `ID` column which I want to update to my `New ID` column which is just **E** inplace of **10**.

```
|   ID  | New ID |
|:-----:|:------:|
| 10022 | EO22   |
| 10157 | E157   |
| 10015 | E015   |
| 10204 | E204   |
| 10216 | E216   |
| 10264 | E264   |
```

Here, I can't use REPLACE because that will replace entire data.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula:

```
="E" & Right(A1,3)
```